# How to define a preprocessor macro name

Tags: c++, preprocessor, conditional-compilation

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
 
                 cout<<"key_str"<<key_str<<endl;
                 cout<<"val_str"<<val_str<<endl;
 #endif
```

I am reading others' code with a `_DEBUG` macro. I want to print these cout's content to screen.
Is there an option to *turn it on* either in *compiling* or *running* the program? I am new to c++.

Comment: Elsewhere you mentioned that you are using a makefile. Have you tried `make debug -f Makefile` (or whatever is documented as the way to get a debug build of that project)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass definitions with the `-D` flag to `g++`:

```
$ g++ -D_DEBUG -g -O0 main.cpp -o main
```

Comment: But it is a make file. and i have to compile with 'make -f Makefile', not directly using g++.

Comment: Also, '-D_DEBUG'? Is there a space? Is there an option to turn on the debug when I run it executable, if I don't recompile it?

Comment: makefiles almost always have a `CFLAGS` or `CPPFLAGS` that are either generated with `./configure` (which you can use) or edit manually

Comment: @marlon: The space is optional.  No, the whole point of a macro is that it affects the code which gets compiled.  In this example, if `_DEBUG` wasn't defined at compile time, then the code to print the messages isn't even part of the executable, so there is no possible way to have it run without recompiling again.  If you want that, use a variable and a regular `if` statement instead.

Comment: If you want to enable it from code for the next compilation add a line "#define DEBUG" at the beginning of your source file (or in a header file you include)

Comment: maybe you have a rule debug or similar or makefile option, and so `make debug`.